How does the coefficient of restitution affect the velocity after?
I know that for a vertical or a horizontal impact the coefficient of resititution (e) affects the velocity in that direction $e=\frac{v'_{2x}-v'_{1x}}{v_{1x}-v_{2x}}$, or y if it is vertical. But what happens if the impact is angled 
Then you'll get both x and y components. Are those equal to eachother? i.e  $e=\frac{v'_{2x}-v'_{1x}}{v_{1x}-v_{2x}}=\frac{v'_{2y}-v'_{1y}}{v_{1y}-v_{2y}}$, And how would you calculate the velocity after

No, the collision needs to conserve momentum in each component. The coefficient of restitution will be different for each direction.

If the floor is smooth and there is no friction then the surface can apply impulse in only one direction and so apply the definition of "e" in only vertical component of velocity or more precisely the component of velocity perpendicular to the surface. The component of velocity parallel to the surface remains same. If the floor has coefficient of friction "$\mu$" then a horizontal impulse can also be applied on the particle depending on the particle ranging from :
$0\le f\le N\cdot\mu$   [where $f$ is the parallel impulse and $N$ is the perpendicular impulse.]
After calculating impulse parallel to surface impulse momentum theorem can be applied to calculate the component of velocity parallel to the surface.
